# LG G3 | An alternative to lock files in gallery?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, gallery, lg-g3

Before the marshmallow update I could easily hide some folders on the gallery app. Now with the marshmallow they changed this functionality to *lock files*. The problem is that large files take too long to lock and when the screen goes off during the process it simply doesn't not lock the file!

Answer (score 0):

What you can try as an alternative is to locate the file/folder using File Manager or File Explorer. Then simply rename the file. Just add a dot at the beginning of the file name, and that file/folder will be changed to a hidden file/folder.